# Create a line using a list of coordinates in python GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, line, coordinates

I've been trying to create a graph using a create_line and a list of (x,y) points.

```
import Tkinter
Screen = [a list of screen coordinates]
World = []
for x,y in screen:
    World.append(somefunctiontochange(x,y))
    if len(World) >= 2:
        Canvas.create_line(World)
```

The line doesn't show in my canvas though, and no error was given. Any help?

Comment: You should mention that you're using Tkinter (I think?)

Comment: Yeah i have all those. This is just a segment of my overall code. Ill edit it.

Comment: For code to show properly on this site, you need to [indent it by 4 spaces](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/221039).

Comment: yeah. but could you answer my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Took me a while but this is how you draw to a canvas in the way you want:

```
import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")
root.title("Drawing lines to a canvas")

cv = tk.Canvas(root,height="500",width="500",bg="white")
cv.pack()

def linemaker(screen_points):
    """ Function to take list of points and make them into lines
    """
    is_first = True
    # Set up some variables to hold x,y coods
    x0 = y0 = 0
    # Grab each pair of points from the input list
    for (x,y) in screen_points:
        # If its the first point in a set, set x0,y0 to the values
        if is_first:
            x0 = x
            y0 = y
            is_first = False
        else:
            # If its not the fist point yeild previous pair and current pair
            yield x0,y0,x,y
            # Set current x,y to start coords of next line
            x0,y0 = x,y

list_of_screen_coods = [(50,250),(150,100),(250,250),(350,100)]

for (x0,y0,x1,y1) in linemaker(list_of_screen_coods):
    cv.create_line(x0,y0,x1,y1, width=1,fill="red")

root.mainloop()
```

You need to supply create_line with the x,y positions at the start and end point of the line, in the example code above (works) I'm drawing four lines connecting points (50,250),(150,100),(250,250),(350,100) in a zigzag line

Its worth pointing out also that the x,y coords on a canvas start at the top left rather than the bottom left, think of it less like a graph with the x,y = 0,0 in the bottom left of the canvas and more how you would print to a page starting in top left corner moving to the right in the x and with the y incrementing as you move down the page.

I used:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_canvas.htm as reference.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But i was thinking about rather a set of lines connecting to each other by points. Like a graph.

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't getting errors and you're certain your function is being called, you probably have one of three problems:

**Is your canvas visible?** A common mistake for beginners is to either forget to pack/grid/place the canvas, or to neglect to do that for all of its containers. An easy way to verify is to temporarily give your canvas a really bright background so that it stands out from the rest of the GUI.

**Have you set the scroll region?** The other explanation is that the drawing is happening, but it's happening in an area that is outside the viewable portion of the canvas. You should be setting the `scrollregion` attribute of the canvas after creating your drawings, to make sure everything you're drawing can be made visible.

**Does your canvas and canvas objects have an appropriate color?** It's possible that you've changed the background of the canvas to black (since you don't show that code in your question), and you're using a default color of black when creating your lines.